# how can I read time in miliseconds twice in gawk

Tags: time, gawk, milliseconds

Gawk trying to get time in milisec start and end of program. 
1st "echo %time%" | getline startT, 
works like a charm. 
2nd "echo %time%" | getline stopT, 
yeilds NADA. for some reason the second %time% does not work.
......any ideas? Thanks, Joe

Comment: Post a [mcve] so we can try to help you (chances are you're not closing the pipe between invocations but without seeing the full code...).

Answer (score 0):

example
BEGIN{
          "echo %time%" | getline t1
          "echo %time%" | getline t2

```
      print "t1="t1"  t2="t2
```

}

This yeilds
t1= 9:36:12.60  t2=

using
gawk
windows environment

for now I'm using
    system("echo %time% > starttime.txt")
    getline P_start < "starttime.txt"